# How to properly erase and use a CD-RW

Tags: data-cd, wodim

There is this CD-RW which I always used to burn distros' CDs. All of a sudden it acts like a normal CD.

When I mount it, it gets mounted this way:

```
 - Proprietary: Root
 - Access: Read only
 - Group: Root
 - Access: Read only
 - Other: Read only
```

I thought I could manually mount it as Read-write. These are the results:

```
alex@Sargon:~$ sudo mount -o rw '/media/cdrom0'
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

I read that this "write protection" is something that gets written on the CD-RW in case it gets "finalized" when it gets burned, but that should be possible to get it out just by erasing the CD. Thought, if I try do to that via `wodim`, this is what happens:

```
alex@Sargon:~$ wodim --devices
wodim: No such file or directory. 
Cannot open SCSI driver!
For possible targets try 'wodim --devices' or 'wodim -scanbus'.
For possible transport specifiers try 'wodim dev=help'.
For IDE/ATAPI devices configuration, see the file README.ATAPI.setup from
the wodim documentation.
```

Ideas about how to proceed?

### EDIT 1 - 6th November 2019

I followed the instructions by @telcoM and got some result.

I was able to install `lsscsi` and got this output:

```
alex@Sargon:~$ lsscsi -g
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST500LT012-1DG14 SDM1  /dev/sda   /dev/sg0 
[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GUA0N     1.00  /dev/sr0   /dev/sg1
```

So `wodim` was able to get some result. It looks to me like it recognizes it as a proper CD-RW disc:

```
alex@Sargon:~$ wodim dev=/dev/sg1 --prcap
wodim: Operation not permitted. Warning: Cannot raise RLIMIT_MEMLOCK limits.
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
Identification : 'DVDRAM GUA0N    '
Revision       : '1.00'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.

Drive capabilities, per MMC-3 page 2A:

  Does read CD-R media
  Does write CD-R media
  Does read CD-RW media
  Does write CD-RW media
  Does read DVD-ROM media
  Does read DVD-R media
  Does write DVD-R media
  Does read DVD-RAM media
  Does write DVD-RAM media
  Does support test writing

  Does read Mode 2 Form 1 blocks
  Does read Mode 2 Form 2 blocks
  Does read digital audio blocks
  Does restart non-streamed digital audio reads accurately
  Does support Buffer-Underrun-Free recording
  Does read multi-session CDs
  Does read fixed-packet CD media using Method 2
  Does not read CD bar code
  Does read R-W subcode information
  Does return R-W subcode de-interleaved and error-corrected
  Does read raw P-W subcode data from lead in
  Does return CD media catalog number
  Does return CD ISRC information
  Does support C2 error pointers
  Does not deliver composite A/V data

  Does play audio CDs
  Number of volume control levels: 256
  Does support individual volume control setting for each channel
  Does support independent mute setting for each channel
  Does not support digital output on port 1
  Does not support digital output on port 2

  Loading mechanism type: tray
  Does support ejection of CD via START/STOP command
  Does not lock media on power up via prevent jumper
  Does allow media to be locked in the drive via PREVENT/ALLOW command
  Is currently in a media-locked state
  Does not support changing side of disk
  Does not have load-empty-slot-in-changer feature
  Does not support Individual Disk Present feature

  Maximum read  speed:  4234 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Current read  speed:  4234 kB/s (CD  24x, DVD  3x)
  Maximum write speed:  1764 kB/s (CD  10x, DVD  1x)
  Current write speed:  1764 kB/s (CD  10x, DVD  1x)
  Rotational control selected: CLV/PCAV
  Buffer size in KB: 512
  Copy management revision supported: 1
  Number of supported write speeds: 1
  Write speed # 0:  1764 kB/s CLV/PCAV (CD  10x, DVD  1x)

Supported CD-RW media types according to MMC-4 feature 0x37:
  Does write multi speed       CD-RW media
  Does write high  speed       CD-RW media
  Does write ultra high speed  CD-RW media
  Does write ultra high speed+ CD-RW media
```

Still I'm not sure about what to do at this point.

In the meanwhile I tried to use `k3b`, which wasn't able to erase the disk too and got this output:

```
Devices
-----------------------
HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GUA0N 1.00 (/dev/sr0, CD-R, CD-RW, CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R DL, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL) [DVD-ROM, DVD-R Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Jump, DVD-RAM, DVD-RW Restricted Overwrite, DVD-RW Sequential, DVD+RW, DVD+R, DVD+R Dual Layer, CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW] [SAO, TAO, RAW, SAO/R96P, SAO/R96R, RAW/R16, RAW/R96P, RAW/R96R, Restricted Overwrite, Layer Jump] [%7]

System
-----------------------
K3b Version: 2.0.3
KDE Version: 4.14.26
QT Version:  4.8.7
Kernel:      4.9.0-11-amd64

Used versions
-----------------------
cdrecord: 1.1.11

cdrecord
-----------------------
scsidev: '/dev/sr0'
devname: '/dev/sr0'
scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.27
Wodim version: 1.1.11
SCSI buffer size: 64512
Beginning DMA speed test. Set CDR_NODMATEST environment variable if device
communication breaks or freezes immediately after that.
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
Driveropts: 'burnfree'
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
Identification : 'DVDRAM GUA0N    '
Revision       : '1.00'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Current: 0x000A (CD-RW)
Profile: 0x0015 (DVD-R/DL sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0016 (DVD-R/DL layer jump recording) 
Profile: 0x002B (DVD+R/DL) 
Profile: 0x001B (DVD+R) 
Profile: 0x001A (DVD+RW) 
Profile: 0x0014 (DVD-RW sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0013 (DVD-RW restricted overwrite) 
Profile: 0x0012 (DVD-RAM) 
Profile: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording) 
Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW) (current)
Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R) 
Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x0002 (Removable disk) 
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
Drive buf size : 362208 = 353 KB
Speed set to 1764 KB/s
Current Secsize: 2048
ATIP info from disk:
  Indicated writing power: 2
  Reference speed: 6
  Is not unrestricted
  Is erasable
  Disk sub type: High speed Rewritable (CAV) media (1)
  ATIP start of lead in:  -11077 (97:34/23)
  ATIP start of lead out: 359849 (79:59/74)
  1T speed low:  4 1T speed high: 10
  2T speed low:  2 2T speed high: 10
  power mult factor: 2 6
  recommended erase/write power: 5
  A1 values: 24 2C DC
  A2 values: 14 A4 4A
  A3 values: 04 C4 80
Disk type:    Phase change
Manuf. index: 11
Manufacturer: Mitsubishi Chemical Corporation
Starting to write CD/DVD at speed  10.0 in real BLANK mode for single session.
Last chance to quit, starting real write in    2 seconds.
   1 seconds.
   0 seconds. Operation starts.
Performing OPC...
Blanking PMA, TOC, pregap
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), blank unit scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  A1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 71 00 03 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 51 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x3 Medium Error, deferred error, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x51 Qual 0x00 (erase failure) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
cmd finished after 17.009s timeout 9600s
/usr/bin/wodim: Cannot blank disk, aborting.
/usr/bin/wodim: Some drives do not support all blank types.
/usr/bin/wodim: Try again with wodim blank=all.

cdrecord command:
-----------------------
/usr/bin/wodim -v gracetime=2 dev=/dev/sr0 speed=10 -tao driveropts=burnfree blank=fast
```

I tried to change the permissions with `k3bsetup` and tried to set the burning group as `alex`, but it didn't change anything.

### EDIT 2 - Later that day...

I tried to erase the disk with `wodim` as suggested below:

```
alex@Sargon:~$ wodim dev=/dev/sg1 blank=all -force
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'HL-DT-ST'
Identification : 'DVDRAM GUA0N    '
Revision       : '1.00'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-R/DVD-RW.
Using generic SCSI-3/mmc   CD-R/CD-RW driver (mmc_cdr).
Driver flags   : MMC-3 SWABAUDIO BURNFREE 
Supported modes: TAO PACKET SAO SAO/R96P SAO/R96R RAW/R16 RAW/R96P RAW/R96R
Speed set to 1764 KB/s
Waiting for drive to calm down.
Starting to write CD/DVD at speed  10.0 in real force BLANK mode for single session.
Last chance to quit, starting real write in    0 seconds. Operation starts.
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), blank unit scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  A1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 71 00 03 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 51 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x3 Medium Error, deferred error, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x51 Qual 0x00 (erase failure) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
cmd finished after 24.064s timeout 9600s
Starting to write CD/DVD at speed  10.0 in real force BLANK mode for single session.
No chance to quit anymore. Operation starts.
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), blank unit scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  A1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 71 00 03 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 51 00 00 00
Sense Key: 0x3 Medium Error, deferred error, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x51 Qual 0x00 (erase failure) Fru 0x0
Sense flags: Blk 0 (not valid) 
cmd finished after 16.381s timeout 9600s
wodim: Cannot blank disk, aborting.
```

I tried also with root rights but it goes the same way.

Comment: I don't think a normal user can do that. What does `sudo wodim --devices` tell you to do, Alex?

Comment: I get exactly the same output :(

Comment: Wodim is the result from a anti-social and anti-OSS campaign from Debian. It is unmaintained since 13 years, do not use it, is usually does not work. Rather use the original `cdrecord` program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying with several programs, guis, and even switching to Windows, I wondered if the issue might have been related to the drive.

Aaaaand... it was. I just went to an other PC and was able to erase it in 30 seconds.

Not sure why I can burn but can't erase through this one. Go figure.

Thanks nonetheless to @telcoM for the effort.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the erase operation might need consistent high-power use of the drive's laser, as much or perhaps even more so than burning. If the laser or its power capacitors are starting to show their age, and that particular media has its optical power requirements on the high side of the standard tolerances, your drive might just be incapable of putting out enough optical power to consistently erase the disk.

Comment: @telcoM you need to regard that problems with drives usually are caused from using `wodim`. You are however correct if the problem is present the same way with the original `cdrecord` software.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the `lsscsi` command available, or can you install it? 
If possible, run `lsscsi -g` and identify your CD-RW drive from the listing.

Your CD-RW drive is probably `/dev/sr0`, but it will also have a `/dev/sg*` device associated with it. This is the "generic SCSI device" that allows sending more specialized commands to the drive. The `lsscsi -g` output should indicate which generic SCSI device corresponds to your CD-RW drive.

Once you know that your CD-RW drive is accessible as e.g. `/dev/sg1`, you can try `wodim dev=/dev/sg1 --prcap`. If that command produces a long listing of CD/DVD features and your drive's support of each of them, you've find the correct `dev=` parameter for your drive.

It looks like some change has caused `wodim` to fail to auto-detect the devices: on my Debian 10 system, the same thing happens, but if I specify the `/dev/sg*` device to `wodim` manually, it works. You can use `/etc/wodim.conf` to make a specific device parameter the default for `wodim`, so you won't have to keep typing it.

Mounting a CD-RW as a regular writable filesystem requires packet writing, and you would use `/dev/pktcdvd/pktcdvd0` instead of the regular `/dev/sr0` CD device. However, the `pktcdvd` driver has been marked as deprecated by the Linux kernel developers, since apparently very few people use it. The driver has not yet been removed from the kernel source code, but after the deprecation notice, some distributions may have removed it from their standard kernel configurations.

To erase (blank) your CDRW with `wodim` even if it looks unerasable:

```
wodim dev=/dev/sg1 blank=all -force
```

To get rid of the need to specify the `dev=` parameter, you can edit `/etc/wodim.conf` to make `/dev/sg1` the default device, in two steps:

1.) add a nickname "burner" for the device by adding this line to the end of the file:

```
burner=    /dev/sg1 -1  -1  burnfree
```

2.) edit the `CDR_DEVICE` setting near the beginning of the file to use the nickname:

```
#CDR_DEVICE=cdrom  # this line commented out and the next line added
CDR_DEVICE=burner
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think we made some advancement. Still, I'm not sure about what to do after `wodim dev=/dev/sg1 --prcap`. I edited my opening post.

Comment: Edited again :(